# Batch Commands to edit registry entries for Local Security Policy/User Rights Assignment

Tags: batch-file, registry

Is there some batch command out there that will allow me to edit a server's Local Security Policy / User Rights Assignment ?
Looking to add a user to 3 of the policies here: "Allow Log On Locally" , "Log On as a Batch Job" and "Log On as a Service"
I prep servers for many companies preparing for the installation of my companies software. Many pieces of this software need user credentials for services and batch jobs.

I'm looking for some registry keys to edit so I can add them to my server prep script.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the **ntrights** command from the resource kit, see more info here http://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html and then try this

```
ntrights -u userName +r SeInteractiveLogonRight
```

Comment: I was looking for something that would come with the standard install for Server... This program, which has been mentioned many times on S.O., is not standard. Thank you though, much appreciated for your time.

Comment: Windows Resource Kits are the **standard** set of extra commands and technical documentation that are not part of the product but that are distributed and supported by microsoft.

Comment: These can be added to 2008 server roles? What are they a part of?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open-source tool for this:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PrivMan

**PrivMan** is an open-source alternative to the **ntrights** utility found in the Windows Resource Kit. Some of the differences between **PrivMan** and **ntrights** are as follows:

- **PrivMan** supports adding and removing multiple privileges/rights, whereas **ntrights** only supports one privilege/right at a time.
- **PrivMan** can test whether an account has one or more privileges/rights, but **ntrights** cannot.
- **PrivMan** can list accounts with a specified privilege/rights, but **ntrights** cannot.
- **PrivMan** can report on all accounts and assigned privileges/rights, but **ntrights** cannot.